# Is ./protoc-gen-go slow?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am trying to compile a .proto file to generate code. Does it last much time to compile or am I doing something wrong?  Compilation seems to be endless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling a protobuf file should last a few seconds at most.

But it sounds like you are invoking `protoc-gen-go` directly. It is designed to be used as a plugin to protoc, so you should use:

`protoc --go_out=. msg.proto`

If it cannot find the generator binary because it's not in your path, you'll also need to specify `--plugin=protoc-gen-go=/path/to/protoc-gen-go`.

When used stand alone, `protoc-gen-go` will be waiting for input on stdin, and will display error message once you terminate it with `ctrl-D`.